# "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. How to use state on "useCallback"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update state in Child component but it doesn't work. Actually, there're a lot of items. And I want to list each item with `map`.

The error:

> React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

The code:

```
const renderItems = useCallback(() => {
  return items.map((item, idx) => {
    const { name } = room
    const [isCopiedURL, setIsCopiedURL] = useState(false)

    return (
      <li key={idx}>
        <CopyToClipboard
          text={item.name}
          onCopy={() => setIsCopiedURL(true)}
        >
          {item.name}
        </CopyToClipboard>
      </li>
    )
  })
}, [items])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert the mapped return value to a component and then use `useState` within it since hooks are meant to be used within functional components.

According to the rules of rules you can use them within functions such as map in your case

```
const Item = ({room, item}) => {
    const { name } = room
    const [isCopiedURL, setIsCopiedURL] = useState(false)

    return (
      <li key={idx}>
        <CopyToClipboard
          text={item.name}
          onCopy={() => setIsCopiedURL(true)}
        >
          {item.name}
        </CopyToClipboard>
      </li>
    )
}

...
const renderItems = useCallback(() => {
  return items.map((item, idx) => {
     return <Item room={room} item={item} key={idx} />
  })
}, [items])
...
```

Comment: It's a nice hack , liked it &#9829;